# What's the position of the Catholic Christianity and the new testament regards homosexuality?

Tags: catholicism, old-testament, new-testament

What's the position of catholic Christianity regards homosexuality?

Does the new testament agree with the old testament approach to homosexuality?

The new testament approach appears in Lev ([18,22-23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2018&version=NIV)):
It condemns it and even it seems it is equal to sexual relations with animals:

> “‘Do not have sexual relations with a man as one does with a woman;
> That is detestable. “‘Do not have sexual relations with an animal and
> defile yourself with it. A woman must not present herself to an animal
> to have sexual relations with it; that is a perversion.

[Later](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2020&version=NIV) on in the same book:
“‘If a man has sexual relations with a man as one does with a woman, both of them have done what is detestable. They are to be put to death; their blood will be on their own heads.

Comment: The question needs to first define the 'OT' approach, before asking for a comparison of the 'NT approach'. The question also needs to be scoped. Literature in the public domain clearly indicates a spectrum of belief in this area. The question needs to specify which Christian group is the subject of the question.

Comment: Edited and added information. Although I believe those who're gonna answer this question, knows all what I mentioned.

Comment: _Questions that can be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed. They must be edited to ask for one perspective, or to explicitly ask for an overview of all Christian positions._ [See the Tour and the Help in regard to this aspect of the site.}

Comment: It seems a diplomatic way to avoid this question. Almost, anything can be answered this way. But I have a solution. I will ask about the biggest and most common movements in Christianity. I will repeat this question for catholics and for protestant etc.

Comment: "It seems a diplomatic way to avoid this question" no; it's because the different groups do not agree (for a variety of reasons including underlying premises) and thus it makes the voting system, etc impractical. You don't get a meaningful result if people simply are inclined to vote up or down according to how an answer aligns with their doctrinal views.

Comment: LGBT is a very broad topic, and each denomination will have various views on questions of sexuality and gender. It's probably better to separate it into a question about non-heterosexuality, and then a separate question for gender issues.

Comment: Ok, I will ask about homosexuality.

Comment: As an aside, one is permitted intercourse with one's properly wedded spouse. As one can properly wed neither a person of the same sex, nor a beast, it follows that those acts are equivalent; that is, they are both variations on adultery.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the new testament agree with the old testament approach to homosexuality?

There are two issues here:

- Is it wrong?
- What should be done about it?

The Hebrew and Greek scriptures are in total agreement that it is wrong.
Whatever was a sin for the Israelites, is a sin for Christians; God does not change, nor do his laws.

Where the difference comes in is:

- The Hebrew scriptures contain civil laws for running the *physical* nation of Israel.
  These laws include penalties that are to be administered by the state.
- The Greek scriptures describe Christians as the *spiritual* nation of Israel, separate from worldly affairs.
  Christians are to follow the civil laws of whatever country they live in (except where it would be a sin to do so).

So:

- Practicing homosexuality is a sin.
- Ancient Israel enforced laws against it.
- Christians do not enforce laws, but they should reject as un-Christian any people that knowingly break God's laws.

Note that this answer is not specific to homosexuality.
For instance, while Leviticus 20 condemns practicing homosexuals to death, that same chapter also says:

> A man or woman who is a medium or spiritist among you must be put to death.

These penalties were part of the Israelite civil law.

For Christians, the penalties are irrelevant.
It is sufficient for them to know that practicing homosexuality and consulting with mediums (even reading the daily newspaper horroscope), are sins to be avoided.

Comment: So are you saying for Christians the punishment system is needless and irrelevant, right?

Comment: @Foreignaffairs, I'm saying that it is not up to Christians to punish anyone; tbe duty of Christians is to set a good example.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Christians are kind of angels who don't need a punishment system? Crime is irrelevant to Christians only to Israelites?  (the nation where Jesus came from)

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any *Catholic* support for the idea that, "For Christians, the penalties are irrelevant."  This part of your answer seems to deviate from Catholicism.

Comment: @Foreignaffairs, I'm not saying that crime is irrelevant. I'm saying that enforcing the law is up to the state, not to individual Christians, who generally should follow the local laws of whatever country they live in.  (Anciently, it happened to be Israel that also functioned as the state, and so was also responsible for enforcement.)

Comment: @zippy2006, at various times in history, the Catholic Church has functioned as the state (or had strong control over it). Consider "The Holy Roman Empire", which was both a state with a religion and a religion with a state. This is similar to ancient Israel, which was both a state and a religion.